# Where to download the Windows Update Agent (WUA) 7.4 for WSUS 3.0 SP2

Tags: windows, wsus

Does anyone know where to download the **Windows Update Agent (WUA) 7.4**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387285(VS.85).aspx](http://web.archive.org/web/20090827120956/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387285(VS.85).aspx)

Following this 7.2 is the latest version  (but the links to the different versions are provided in the comments)

Answer (score 0):

To obtain Windows Update Agent version 7.4.7600.226, go to this page. There are download links there:

[Information for network administrators about how to obtain the latest Windows Update Agent @ Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/information-for-network-administrators-about-how-to-obtain-the-latest-windows-update-agent-c1ebc7ca-27c3-e6b0-5da9-a1c6ffe12e82).